# With KVM/Qemu is it possible to fake a complete disk layout for the guest?

Tags: kvm, qemu

What I am wondering is whether a QCOW2 (or any other format really) would allow me to fake a physical extent to the extent that I could mix and match files as backing store and partitions.

That is to say, if I have a physical disk `/dev/sda2` which I'd like the guest to use (exclusively, of course) would it be possible to prepare some kind of disk image that contains, say, its on `/dev/hda{1..4}` and the `/dev/sda2` from the host would appear as, say, `/dev/hda1` inside the guest and the other partitions from the disk image would be backed by files (or the automatically growing) disk image itself.

Essentially what I'd need could be achieved by (just imagining one possible method) supplying a partition table and images that have been set up with a tool like `kpartx` or `losetup` ... because once I can use `kpartx`/`losetup` things should be rather flexible.

Is there anything like that out there?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but it's not really something I would recommend.

Here is an example using four small disk image files, which you safely use for experimentation. You could substitute a real device for any of these as you saw fit.

```
# Create four empty disk image files
dd bs=1M count=1 </dev/zero >img.1
dd bs=1M count=100 </dev/zero >img.2
dd bs=1M count=100 </dev/zero >img.3
dd bs=1M count=1 </dev/zero >img.4

# Convert them into block devices
losetup /dev/loop1 img.1
losetup /dev/loop2 img.2
losetup /dev/loop3 img.3
losetup /dev/loop4 img.4

# Build the array. There is no metadata written anywhere that records the array
# construction - you really are on your own with this one if it goes wrong
mdadm --build /dev/md0 --level linear --raid-devices 4 /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2 /dev/loop3 /dev/loop4

# Create partition table
# This should match the sizes of the image files (above)
parted --align none /dev/md0 <<'x'
  unit MiB
  mklabel gpt
  mkpart primary 1 101
  mkpart primary 101 201
  mkpart primary 201 100%
  quit
x
```

The 1MB partitions at the beginning and end of the composite linear "disk" are for storing the GPT (it writes two). The two 100MB partitions represent your data.

Note that RAID0 and LINEAR are not the same; RAID0 stripes data across all the "disks", whereas LINEAR simply concatenates the "disks" together.

In real code you shouldn't rely on `/dev/loop1`, etc. being available. Instead, use something like `lo1=$(losetup --show --find img.1)` and then reference the loop device as `"$lo1"`.

Comment: This seems a viable way, but as you indicate in your introduction, far from ideal. Let's see whether others also have ideas. Thank you for your answer!